# How can i use setActivityForResult() in an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, voice-recognition

I have seen many threads about this question, but I cannot find any solution.
My problem is that I want to run Google voice recognizer in the background by using Asynctask, but I cannot use `setActivityForResult()` in AsyncTask sub-class. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

If there is any other approach to achieve my goal then please suggest it.
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code to understand the problem better:-
My MainActivity:-

```
package com.mrg.simonsays;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
BackgroundRecognise.execute();
}
}
```

I don't know what to give the parameters for execute() method.
BackgroundRecognise activity:-

```
package com.mrg.simonsays;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

public class BackgroundRecognise extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    String str = "";
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Give Your Command");
BackgroundRecognise.this.startActivityForResult(i, 0);
 }
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub if
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        ArrayList<String> results = data
                .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            str = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo).toString();
            for (String i : results) {
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(i)) {
                    Intent LaunchIntent = pm
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
                    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

What I am basically trying to do is: I want to run Google voice recognizer in background, using AsyncTask. But i cannot use startActivityForResult() in any of its methods. Can anyone please help me how to do it?

Comment: Use context of the Activity to call setActivityForResult

Comment: I have done that too but still it doesn't work. I have edited my question, so please can you look at it again? It would really help me

Answer (score 0):

Put the [**`startActivityForResult`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) usage inside of:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //put here
 }
```

Note: `onPostExecute` is part of the Async class.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please answer for me again.